# How to display trailing whitespaces in the text file?

Tags: command-line, osx, cat, whitespace

I'd like to be able to print and see the trailing whitespaces in the text file (just display, not remove).

I've tried with `cat -v` which suppose to display non-printing characters, but it doesn't display them as expected (no visual difference between the lines). E.g.

```
$ printf "foo\nbar \t\n" > file.txt
$ cat -v file.txt 
foo
bar
```

By print/display whitespaces I mean some visual human indication that the trailing whitespace is there in comparison to other lines without, either by some special character, color (like when files are displayed using `git diff`) or something similar.

Is there any other way?

---

Note: I'm on macOS Sierra, however I've got access to both GNU and BSD `cat` commands:

```
$ type -a cat
cat is /usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin/cat
cat is /bin/cat
$ cat --version
cat (GNU coreutils) 8.28
$ /bin/cat --version
/bin/cat: illegal option -- -
usage: cat [-benstuv] [file ...]
```

Comment: Thanks, seems to work fine, at least better than `-v`. `-E` doesn't exist for `/bin/cat`, but I've got GNU `cat` installed as well.

Comment: `cat -v` does work, it just doesn’t do what you think it does — try `cat -v /dev/urandom | head` to see how it affects output.

Comment: @kenorb  `-E` does exist for `/bin/cat` , which version are you talking about

Comment: `cat -v` prints non-printing characters fine, however whitespace is still a whitespace, so it's not really human visible in the terminal.

Comment: @Sanket $ `/bin/cat -E file.txt` -> `/bin/cat: illegal option -- E`.

Comment: `# /bin/cat -E firstOne.txt `
It outputs the content "kkjkl" my case

Answer (score 5):

`gnu cat` has the `-E` switch for that so with an input like

```
printf " one \ntwo \t\n"
```

it will print

```
 one $
two    $
```

There are many ways to emulate that behaviour e.g. use `sed` in "raw" mode:

```
sed -n l infile
```

or

```
paste -d '$' infile /dev/null
```

or use any text processing tool to add a `$` before each newline...

You might also try something like

```
less -p '[[:blank:]]+$' infile
```

which will highlight the pattern (in this case the trailing blanks)...